# OpenLayers 3 VectorTile Layer Reload style on zoom

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

I have a vectorlayer in my map and would like to change the style of features when the zoom level changes. Is this possible?

```
var vlayer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    renderMode: 'vector',
    preload: Infinity,
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        attributions: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">' + 'OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
            extent: ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857').getExtent(),
            resolutions: resolutions
        }),
        tilePixelRatio: 16,
        tileUrlFunction: tileUrlFunction,
        projection: 'EPSG:3857'
    })
    , style: stylefunction()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        vlayer
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0,0],
        zoom: 15
    })
});
```

Comment: This may be the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37873359/3361339

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreDubé. That is what I am currently doing... Unfortunately the issue is that OpenLayers only styles the object once... If I have multiple styles... For example, a road is 1 pixel wide at zoom level 10, but I want that same road to be 2 pixels wide at zoom level 11, the function to style the object is never called after the initial style... The road remains 1 pixel wide no matter what zoom level I go to because the object already has a style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change it up to the zoom after setting styles on the features,
you can set `change:resolution` event on view.
something like this:

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution', function(e) {
  var features = map.getLayers().getArray()[0].getSource().getFeatures();

  if (map.getView().getZoom() == 2) {
    for (var i = 0, len = features.length; i < len; i++) {
      features[i].setStyle(newstyle);
    }  
  } else {
    for (var i = 0, len = features.length; i < len; i++) {
      features[i].setStyle(stylee);
    } 
  }
});
```

sample codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrEGoX)
when the map zoom is 2 then the color of features turn to blue.

Comment: Thanks @Chase Choi... I will try this a little later and mark it as an answer if it works... This appears to be what I was looking for, however. As I want to restyle many features this might be fairly CPU intensive, however, it looks like my only option.

Comment: Your answer appears to be the solution. I have one problem, however... I am using OpenLayers3 and I am using a `ol.layer.VectorTile` object. Your `map.getLayers().getArray()[0].getSource().getFeatures()` line throws an exception . I believe that line works for a `ol.layer.Vector` object. From the research I have done on the Internet, OpenLayers does not allow me to pull Features from the VectorTile object.